# Oracle spatial within_distance perforemance

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

Im having troubles with query tuning,
I have 3 tables (a few milions rows),b (about 200000 rows),c (about 200000 rows)) each have indexes sdo_geometry column (polygons).
I try to query and get object that table a is within N distance from table b and c and a I also filter the tables a bit.

the query looks like (Oracle 12c Exadata machine):

```
SELECT a.id, b.number, c.number
FROM a, b ,c 
WHERE
** I filter here some rows, like a.date > XXXX AND b.status = Y **
sdo_within_distance(a.shape, c.shape, 'distance=n unit=m') = 'TRUE' AND
sdo_within_distance(a.shape, b.shape, 'distance=n unit=m') = 'TRUE'
```

Im getting realy poor perforemnce while on postgres we are getting much better perforemance.

In the execution plan I see there is high cost nl join.
I tried to change the shapes query order, SDO_JOIN, ORDERED hint but im not able to get good performence.

Is there any way to rewrite this query better?
Is postgis realy better than Oracle 12c spatial for these kind of queries? Or my design is just bad

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFmy.png)

Comment: Can you post the execution plan you get ? What database version ? Is that Enterprise edition ?

Comment: The database version is 12.1.0.2 Enterprise edition.
the execution plan is:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFmy.png

Thanks.

Comment: It might make a difference if you put your other clauses at the end of your statement rather than at the start.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem.
I had some converts from string to number in the where clause because of the tables design.
But I wanted to know how do I know wich column put first in the sdo_within_distance? I mean both orders will give the same result right?
sdo_within_distance(a.shape, b.shape, 'distance=n unit=m') = 'TRUE' OR
sdo_within_distance(b.shape, a.shape, 'distance=n unit=m') = 'TRUE'
How do I decide wich order is better?

Comment: The spatial operators always work the same way. An operator o(a,b) is always performed by taking each b object to search objects a. So the most efficient way for executing o(a,b) is the one where card(b) < card(a). In your case, it depends on how selective your filters on a and b are. At the end the execution time is proportional to card(b). If that is large (say 100000), then execution time can get very long. A better approach is SDO_JOIN who uses both spatial indexes on a and b to find correlated objects.

Comment: Hi, I still cant understand why the cost is so high.
At the execution plan (the last 2 rows) I have spatial index query by index and than
Table access by index rowid (that include the filter where status IN ('status','status2,'status3')) if I remove the IN clause the query is much faster but still the cost is very high.
The column is indexed and the IN clause filter will return 70% rows of the table.

And about the sdo_join, for its work much slower when I use it.